# Nested Polynomial-Time functions

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, polynomial-math

If I run a polynomial-time subroutine a polynomial number of times, what are some examples of a way that this is done in exponential time?

"show that a polynomial number of calls to polynomial time subroutines may
result in an exponential-time algorithm." - a problem of a HW

Comment: Are you sure there exists at least one example?

Comment: Hope so, otherwise im getting a -10% on this hw assignment

Comment: How to define a polynomial time subroutine? Perhaps there is a trick involved somewhere in the problem.

Comment: can you find the trick?

Comment: http://www4.ncsu.edu/~aszanto/MA522/HWSol2.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if we treat this as a "dirty trick" question:

```
def g(a):
    b = 0
    for i in range(a * 2):
        b += 1
    return b

def f(x):
    a = 1
    for i in range(x):
        a = g(a)
```

g(a) runs in O(a), f(x) runs in O(x) times before the call to `g`, but overall it is `O(2 ^ n)`.

Comment: O(a) is not polynomial. Just like knapsack problem with O(NV) but it's not polynomial.

Comment: g is definitely polynomial with respect to its input parameter, but yes, this is a trick solution, which might be wrong.

Comment: The complexity is measured by the input length. To input a only need log(a) bits. So a input with length la will cost O(2^la). It's exponential.

Comment: A simple for loop is exponential? that's something new to me. I guess your computational model if different from mine. Your model implies polylog=poly.

Comment: Sure.Knapsack problem is just two simple loops, but it's NP-Hard. I don't know what computational model that is in your mind. As for me , I read the book written by Sipser, and that is all I know about theory of computation.

Comment: Knapsack is NP-hard with respect to the number of elements, but the two loop version need the weight to be bounded too. So it is NP-hard yes, but not with respect to the max weight.

Comment: I guess you are talking about a model in which `*` takes O(log(n)) time, and you consider this to be polynomial wrt to the length (bits), while I consider `*` to be constant time. And yeah, your definition fits this problem better.

Comment: What? All I see is a `log(n)` loop with `O(1)` time additions.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. But if you run a polynomial time sub routine a polynomial number of times you will never get an exponential time function. After running a polynomial time sub routine a polynomial number of times, you will still get a polynomial time run time complexity.

For example if you run a sub routine with **n<sup>2</sup>** complexity **n<sup>3</sup>** number of times the resulting algorithm will have **n<sup>5</sup>** run time complexity, which is still a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: polynomial times polynomial is still a polynomial. So you will never get an exponential algorithm, unless there are some additional conditions in the question.

Answer (score 0):

f(a) = 2^a

g(b) = sum=0; for (i = 1..b) sum=sum+i

f(a) is O(n)

g(b) is O(n)

g(f(a)) is exponential